# Find all the prime integer solutions to $q^2(p-1)=(p+1)(q+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $p,q$ be prime numbers. Find all the integer solutions to:
$$q^2(p-1) = (p+1)(q+1)$$

---

I am almost sure that $q=2$,$p=7$ is the only solution. Thus I assumed that $p$ and $q$ were both odd to reach a contradiction, but so far I haven't made any progress that way.

Comment: I notice that $q$ cannot be very big, for example.  What have you tried?

Comment: I am almost sure that $q=2, p=7$ is the only solution. Thus I assumed that $p,q$ were both odd to reach a contradiction, but so far I haven't done any progress on that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track assuming that $p,q$ are odd.

Here's the step you may be missing: if $p>2$ is odd, then $(p-1, p+1) = 1$. But $(p+1)$ must divide both sides of the equation. So $(p+1)\mid q^2$. Hence $q$ is even.

Comment: WOAH thanks....

Comment: How did I miss that? :P

Comment: Happens to all of us :)

Comment: $(p−1,p+1)=2$ if $p$ is odd.

Comment: Right you are... give me a sec

Comment: Hmm... seems I can't delete it or fix it. Any ideas? I'm sure this is gonna be the correct kind of approach

Comment: Try reworking a solution from $q^2 | p+1$, since $q^2$ is coprime to $q+1$.

Comment: That gives $q \equiv -1$ (mod $p$)... I couldn't make that work. I've reduced it to the case $p \equiv 1$ (mod $4$)...

Answer (score 4):

We show how to solve a *different* problem, finding the *integer* solutions of $q^2(p-1)=(p+1)(q+1)$. There are not many.

We can have $p=1$, which forces $q=-1$. If $p\ne -1$, then $\left|\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right|\le 3$.

Note that if $|q|\ge 4$ then $\left|\frac{q^2}{q+1}\right|\gt 3$.

So the only candidates for $q$ lie in the interval $-3\le q\le 3$.  Try them all. In each case we get a linear equation for $p$.

If we are really only interested in primes, the only numbers that need to be tried are $q=2$ and $q=3$.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more ... How you got if $p \not = -1$, then $\left|\frac{p+1}{p-1} \right| \leq 3 $...Didn't get this

Answer (score 1):

If we assume $p,q$ are *positive* primes, we can proceed by first showing $q=2$ and then deduce $p=7$.

Note $q-1 = (q^2-1)/(q+1) \lt (p+1)/(p-1)$.  For any  positive prime $p$, the right hand side is at most 3, so $q$ must be less than 4.  Thus $q$ is either 2 or 3.

If $q=3$ we can refine this estimate a little.  Since $q^2$ divides $p+1$, because $q$ and $q+1$ are coprime, for $q=3$ would mean $p+1$ is a multiple of 9.  This first happens for prime $p=17$.  In any case $(p+1)/(p-1)$ would be less than 2, so $q \lt 3$.  This contradiction implies $q=2$.

Plugging that value for $q$ into the original equation quickly gives $p=7$.

For completeness sake you should examine whether one or both $p,q$ can be *negative* primes.

Comment: Negative numbers are typically considered not prime.

Answer (score 0):

$q^2(p−1)=(p+1)(q+1)$

This can be written as:

$\frac{q^2}{q+1} = \frac{p+1}{p-1} = 1 + \frac{2}{p-1}$

In other words, subtracting 1 from both sides,

$\frac{q^2 - q - 1}{q+1} = \frac{2}{p-1}$

Two cases here:

1) p = 2. So $q^2 - q - 1 = q+1$.
Gives: $q^2 - 2q - 2 = 0$. Easy to see this has no integer solutions (just solve the quadratic equation).

2) p is an odd prime. Let p = 2k + 1.

Then $q + 1 = k(q^2 - q - 1)$.
So $(q+1)(k+1) = kq^2$.

Now, q and q+1 are co-prime. So are k+1 and k. Unless k or q is 1, this can only mean:

$q+1 = k$ and $k+1 = q^2$
So $q+2 = q^2$
Solving the quadratic, q = 2 or q = -1. 'q is prime' makes us reject q = -1 case. So q = 2. So p = 2k+1 = 2(q+1) + 1 = 7.

Now, suppose k = 1. Then we get:
$2(q+1) = q^2$. This again gives $q^2 - 2q - 2 = 0$ which has no integer solutions.

q = 1 gives:
$2(k+1) = k$. This gives k = -1/2, which is not an integer.

So p = 7, q = 2 is the only solution to this.